# Using Swagger with Auth0

Tags: playframework, swagger, swagger-ui, auth0

I'm trying to use Swagger with Auth0. 
I'm currently using [ApiFirstHand](https://github.com/zalando/api-first-hand) and Swagger-ui to test my api.

Starting with this [example.yaml](https://github.com/zalando/play-swagger-service/blob/master/conf/example.yaml), we can see that `getUserTodos` requires `user, admin:org, admin:public_key` scopes.

Here is the securityDefinitions :

```
securityDefinitions:
  internalOAuth:
    type: oauth2
    scopes:
      user: Grants read/write access to profile info only.
      admin:org: Fully manage organization, teams, and memberships.
      admin:public_key: Fully manage public keys.
    flow: implicit
    # we use a single API here to issue token (for SwaggerUI)
    authorizationUrl: http://localhost:9000/example/token
    # and to validate it later
    x-token-validation-url: http://localhost:9000/example/token
```

My question is, what should be my **user's metadata in Auth0** and my **securityDefinitions in example.yaml** if I want to use Auth0 instead of the internal0Auth ?
Is it possible to use Swagger-UI on top of that ?

I tried

```
securityDefinitions:
  auth0:
    type: oauth2
    scopes:
      openid: Grants access to user_id.
      read:task: Grants read access to task
    flow: accessCode
    authorizationUrl: https://test.eu.auth0.com/authorize
    tokenUrl: https://test.eu.auth0.com/userinfo
    x-token-validation-url: https://test.eu.auth0.com/userinfo
```

with

```
 "user_metadata": {
        "admin:org": true,
        "admin:public_key": true,
        "openid": true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `internalOAuth` or `auth0` are just names which then referenced into the definition of the `security` property of the API call. In a sense you can name it any way you like, just use the right name in the API call definition then.

In your case it probably will look like that:

```
security:
  - auth0:
    - openid
    - admin:org
    - admin:public_key

securityDefinitions:
  auth0:
    type: oauth2
    scopes:
      openid: Grants access to user_id
      admin:org: Fully manage organization, teams, and memberships.
      admin:public_key: Fully manage public keys.
    flow: accessCode
    authorizationUrl: https://test.eu.auth0.com/authorize
    tokenUrl: https://test.eu.auth0.com/userinfo
    x-token-validation-url: https://test.eu.auth0.com/userinfo
paths:
  /some/url:
    get:
      description: Returns something
      summary: cool API endpoint
      security:
        - auth0:
            - admin:org
```

It's hard to define it exactly without knowing your requirements, I think it might be helpful to take a look at swagger specification:

[Security Definitions Object](http://swagger.io/specification/#securityDefinitionsObject)

[Security Requirement Object](http://swagger.io/specification/#securityRequirementObject)

The Swagger UI should work with that, you could try it out by moving the `security.api.yaml` into the `conf` folder and uncommenting line 33 in the `routes` file

Comment: By Auth0, I'm mean this Saas => https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication
It looks like they have some kind of "accessCode" and "implicit" flows but the notion of "scope" doesn't seems to match between Swagger and Auth0.

Comment: I wasn't aware about Auth0, sorry. I think the best way I could help is to create another example in api-first activator template. Would you mind to create an issue [here](https://github.com/zalando/play-swagger-service)?